# Macro para copiar e colocar usando VBA Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Estou aprendendo VBA para agilizar meu serviço na empresa, mas estou travado na seguinte parte:

Estava desenvolvendo uma macro que na teoria faria o seguinte caminho:

- 1° Moveria o mouse até a célula A2
- 2° Copiaria o conteúdo da célula A2
- 3° Colaria esse conteúdo em um bloco de notas especifico

Como ele está na célula A2, a posição do mouse se moveria para barra e daria 1 clique, movendo para Célula A3 e fazendo o loop no processo.

Consegui faze o processo de mouse, tecla de atalho própria. Porém quando chega na parte de copiar, ele esta selecionando 2 célula  e consequentemente dando erro por não conseguir fazer 2 célula ao mesmo tempo... Além do CTRL V que não está funcionando...

Enfim, se alguém puder me ajudar ou desenvolver para mim seria muito grato. Me ajudaria a ver onde estaria errando e me ajudaria no aprendizado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: olá bem-vindo(a) ao SOPt, evite colocar imagens na pergunta é mais difícil para visualizar, edite a pergunta e coloque o código

Answer (score 0):

Eu não tenho certeza se entendi exatamente sua necessidade. O que captei foi que você deseja copiar um conteúdo de uma celular e colar na célula abaixo. Só não esta claro para mim ate quando seria o loop. Como não entendi corretamente fiz dois possíveis cenários.

Este código, apenas insere o valor de A2 em A3.

```
Sub copiarColarSimples()

    'Seleciona a planilha e range em que esta a informação
    Worksheets("Planilha1").Select
        
    'Cola a informação de A2 em A3
    Range("a3").Value = Range("a2").Value
   
End Sub
```

Este loop copia os dados de uma célula apra todas as celular abaixo até que encontre uma celula que possua dado. Ou seja, vai copiar os dados de A2 para A3, depois de A3 para A4 até que uma celula abaixo já possua dados.

```
Sub copiarColarLoop()


    Worksheets("Planilha1").Select
    
    Dim linha As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    linha = 2
    i = 1
    
    While Cells(linha + 2, 1) = ""
    
        Cells(linha + 1, 1).Value = Cells(linha, 1).Value
        linha = linha + 1
    
    Wend
    
End Sub
```

Antes da execução do Loop

[image: Antes no Loop]

Depois da Execução

[image: Depois da execução do loop]